# ORACLE (11.2.0.1.0) - Recursive CTE with a date expression

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

**The right answer on the following question:**

- That is a bug that was fixed in 11.2.0.3 or later if I recall correctly. (11.2.0.1 is no longer supported anyway. 11.2.0.4 is the only 11.2 release that is still supported) – @a_horse_with_no_name
- The bug number is 11840579 and it was fixed in 11.2.0.3 and 12.1.0.1
  – @a_horse_with_no_name

**Question**

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  from_date date,
  to_date date
);

INSERT INTO test(from_date,to_date)
--VALUES('20171101','20171115');
VALUES(TO_DATE('20171101','YYYYMMDD'),TO_DATE('20171115','YYYYMMDD'));
```

The following query in Oracle return only one row (expected 15 rows)

```
WITH dateCTE(from_date,to_date,d,i) AS(
  SELECT from_date,to_date,from_date AS d,1 AS i
  FROM test

  UNION ALL

  SELECT from_date,to_date,d+INTERVAL '1' DAY,i+1
  FROM dateCTE
  WHERE d<to_date
)
SELECT d,i
FROM dateCTE
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36907/8

For test I changed the condition to `i<10`

```
WITH dateCTE(from_date,to_date,d,i) AS(
  SELECT from_date,to_date,from_date AS d,1 AS i
  FROM test

  UNION ALL

  SELECT from_date,to_date,d+INTERVAL '1' DAY,i+1
  FROM dateCTE
  --WHERE d<to_date
  WHERE i<10 -- exit condition
)
SELECT d,i
FROM dateCTE
```

And get the next result

```
| D          | I  |
|------------|----|
| 2017-11-01 |  1 |
| 2017-10-31 |  2 |
| 2017-10-30 |  3 |
| 2017-10-29 |  4 |
| 2017-10-28 |  5 |
| 2017-10-27 |  6 |
| 2017-10-26 |  7 |
| 2017-10-25 |  8 |
| 2017-10-24 |  9 |
| 2017-10-23 | 10 |
```

Why do this recursive query returned bad result in Oracle?

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36907/5

I ran a similar query in SQLServer and I get the right result

```
WITH dateCTE(from_date,to_date,d,i) AS(
  SELECT from_date,to_date,from_date AS d,1 AS i
  FROM test

  UNION ALL

  SELECT from_date,to_date,DATEADD(DAY,1,d),i+1
  FROM dateCTE
  WHERE d<to_date
)
SELECT d,i
FROM dateCTE
```

The right result

```
d           i
2017-11-01  1
2017-11-02  2
2017-11-03  3
2017-11-04  4
2017-11-05  5
2017-11-06  6
2017-11-07  7
2017-11-08  8
2017-11-09  9
2017-11-10  10
2017-11-11  11
2017-11-12  12
2017-11-13  13
2017-11-14  14
2017-11-15  15
```

Why it doesn't work in Oracle? What alternative variants can you suggest?  Thank you!

**Screen shots from a real system:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's working for me in Oracle 11g. Are you sure you have the right values in your test table?

Comment: @pablomatico - Yes, I'm sure. See my demo `SQL Fiddle` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36907/5 I already had this problem before on a real system.

Comment: What is your **exact** Oracle version?

Comment: `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

Comment: That is a bug that was fixed in 11.2.0.3 or later if I recall correctly. (11.2.0.1 is no longer supported anyway. 11.2.0.4 is the only 11.2 release that is still supported)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a sequential from-date to to-date, Use such this select:

```
SELECT  DATE '2017-11-01' + LEVEL - 1 AS D, LEVEL AS I
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATE '2017-11-15' - DATE '2017-11-01' + 1;
```

Comment: Good old `CONNECT BY`. ) I think it works on any Oracle versions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me in Oracle 11.2 Enterprise. Your SQL fiddle, however, plainly shows that it doesn't in every Oracle version.

I remember I had similar problems with dates in recursive queries. So there is a bug, that has been fixed in newer versions. It is very likely, your Oracle version has this bug.

**A workaround:** Get only the integer offsets from the recursive query and add them to the from_date afterwards:

```
WITH dateCTE(from_date, i, iend) AS
(
  SELECT from_date, 1 AS i, to_date - from_date as iend
  FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT from_date, i + 1, iend
  FROM dateCTE
  WHERE i <= iend
)
, dates as (select i, from_date + i - 1 as d from dateCTE)
SELECT d, i
FROM dates;
```

Comment: The bug number is 11840579 and it was fixed in 11.2.0.3 and 12.1.0.1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thank you! Can you write it as answer? And I'll close my question.

Comment: I think your answer should stay (and be accepted) because of the workaround.

Comment: Ok. Thank you a lot any way! I accepted an answer with the `CONNECT BY` statement.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner - Your query doesn't work on this Oracle version - `ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [rworupo.1], [21], [8], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []`. Thank you any way!

Comment: Okay. This bug is just incredible. I've tried with SQL fiddle. It works when replacing `to_date - from_date` with `trunc(to_date - from_date)`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36907/35. Weird.