# Oracle - get previous, current and next year from query

Tags: sql, oracle

Is below example good solution for get previous, current and next year?

```
with cte as(
    Select extract(year from sysdate - 365) as year from dual
    union all
    Select extract(year from sysdate) as year from dual
    union all
    Select extract(year from sysdate + 365) as year from dual
)
Select * from cte


YEAR
-----
2020
2021
2022
```

Or any better solution?

Comment: What is the criteria to be the best?

Comment: @astentx I don' know maybe your example is more correct and has fewer lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yours isn't correct for e.g. leap years on the last day of that year. Look at 2020:

```
SQL> select
  2    extract(year from to_date('31.12.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy') - 365) result
  3  from dual;

    RESULT
----------
      2020

SQL>
```

See? Turns out that "previous" year for date `31.12.2020` is still `2020`.

`ADD_MONTHS` is *safer*, I guess:

```
SQL> select
  2    extract (year from add_months(to_date('31.12.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), -12)) result
  3  from dual;

    RESULT
----------
      2019

SQL>
```

---

```
SQL> select
  2    extract (year from add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12)) previous,
  3    extract (year from add_months(trunc(sysdate),   0)) this,
  4    extract (year from add_months(trunc(sysdate),  12)) next
  5  from dual;

  PREVIOUS       THIS       NEXT
---------- ---------- ----------
      2020       2021       2022

SQL>
```

(`this`, of course, doesn't require `add_months`, but I kept it to make query look prettier).

---

Or, why not simply

```
SQL> select this - 1 as previous,
  2         this,
  3         this + 1 as next
  4  from (select extract(year from sysdate) as this from dual);

  PREVIOUS       THIS       NEXT
---------- ---------- ----------
      2020       2021       2022

SQL>
```

For 3 rows, use a CTE:

```
SQL> with temp (this) as
  2    (select extract(year from sysdate) from dual)
  3  select this - 1 as year from temp union all
  4  select this             from temp union all
  5  select this + 1         from temp;

      YEAR
----------
      2020
      2021
      2022

SQL>
```

Comment: Nice example, I will use your example with union all, I need resault in three rows.

Comment: OK; I added yet another example, have a look.

Comment: Upvoted. But can't you add a recursive cte example too - if someone wants +/- _n_ years.

Comment: @jarlh FYI beware date arithmetic is buggy in some Oracle versions - more info https://stackoverflow.com/q/47526482/653539

Answer (score 3):

I might overlook something but why not just this?

```
with cte as(
    Select extract(year from sysdate) - 1 as year from dual
    union all
    Select extract(year from sysdate)     as year from dual
    union all
    Select extract(year from sysdate) + 1 as year from dual
)
Select * from cte
```